# Extract array elements and create a String from them

Tags: android, arrays

I have got an array through Vector addittion like 
`[1!,2!,3!,4!]`

I have to convert it into a string like

```
{1!2!3!4!}
```

..can you please tell me the name of few methods by which i can make it? Thanks all..

```
String getElement = null;
             for(int j = 0;j<5;j++){
             getElement = dynamicViewtagNames.elementAt(j);

             }
```

I can get elements of this array like this..then I have to convert it into a string.

Comment: Can you please explain in briefly...???

Comment: what are you getting in "getElement" now ?

Comment: @Hardy array ma to 4 data j 6 to ane 6 element mate loop fervi 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you just want to turn this:

> [1!,2!,3!,4!]

into

> {1!2!3!4!}

you can for example make use of the **String.replace()** or **String.replaceAll()** method.

```
String str = "[1!,2!,3!,4!]";
str = str.replace("[", "{");
str = str.replace("]", "}");
str = str.replace(",", "");
```

If [1!,2!,3!,4!] is a **Vector containing the Strings** you showed us above, you could do it like this using a **StringBuffer**:

```
// letz assume this vector has the following content: [1!,2!,3!,4!]
Vector<String> dynamicViewtagNames = new Vector<String>(); 

StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();

b.append("{");

for(int i = 0; i < dynamicViewtagNames.size(); i++) {
    b.append(dynamicViewtagNames.get(i))
}

b.append("}");
String mystring = b.toString();
```

Comment: In your second case, he wants no `,` in the resulting String, which is even easier. Also watch out with `i < 4`. `i < array.length` is more correct.

Comment: I'm aware that its safer, I just coded this quick example :) Thank you tho.

Comment: @Parinita: What do you mean by that? Are you still having problems? Is your [1!,2!,3!,4!] an array? Is it a String?

Comment: the str u took that is not a string I am getting array in a vector...private Vector<String> dynamicViewtagNames = new Vector<String>();

Comment: Allright, so for example the first vector item looks like this: "1!", am I right?

Comment: yes...first i m getting [1!] then [1!,2!] AND [1!,2!,3!] then [1!,2!,3!,4!]

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution

```
 String names = names.replaceAll(",","");
 names = names.replaceAll("[", "{");
 names = names.replaceAll("]", "}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code,

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i<dynamicViewtagNames.length;i++){
    str.append(dynamicViewtagNames[i])
}

str.toString();
```

or you can use:

```
Arrays.toString(dynamicViewtagNames);
```

Thanks